Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') when deploying Mock Aggregator
I am trying to deploy Mock Aggregator, but getting the error as
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
This error is from the internal module called hardhat deploy
I went through some same issues on stack overflow and figured out that most of them were solved by adding
namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
    },
  },

this in their hardhat.config file but as you can see it was already there in my code still i'm getting the same error
I'm unable to get it solved please help me to figure it out
My Mock Deploy Script

const DECIMALS = "8"
const INITIAL_PRICE = "200000000000" // 2000
module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    // If we are on a local development network, we need to deploy mocks!


    if (chainId == 31337) {
        log("Local network detected! Deploying mocks...")
        await deploy("MockV3Aggregator", {
            contract: "MockV3Aggregator",
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: [DECIMALS, INITIAL_PRICE],
        })
        log("Mocks Deployed!")
        log("------------------------------------------------")
        log(
            "You are deploying to a local network, you'll need a local network running to interact"
        )
        log(
            "Please run `npx hardhat console` to interact with the deployed smart contracts!"
        )
        log("------------------------------------------------")
    }
}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]

My hardhat.config
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-solhint");
require('hardhat-deploy');
// require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
// require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("dotenv").config()
require("solidity-coverage")

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */

const COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY = process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY || ""
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL =
    process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL ||
    "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/YOUR-API-KEY"
const PRIVATE_KEY =
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY ||
    "0x11ee3108a03081fe260ecdc106554d09d9d1209bcafd46942b10e02943effc4a"
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || ""

module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    namedAccounts: {
      deployer: {
          default: 0,
      },
    },
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            chainId: 31337,
            // gasPrice: 130000000000,
        },
        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 11155111,
            blockConfirmations: 6,
        },
    },
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            {
                version: "^0.8.17",
            },
            {
                version: "^0.8.7",
            },
            {
              version: "^0.6.6",
            },
        ],
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
        // customChains: [], // uncomment this line if you are getting a TypeError: customChains is not iterable
    },
    gasReporter: {
        enabled: true,
        currency: "USD",
        outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
        noColors: true,
        // coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
    },
    mocha: {
        timeout: 500000,
    },
}

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
};

Error:
Local network detected! Deploying mocks...
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: 
ERROR processing .....Hardhat_Fundme\deploy\00-deploy-mocks.js:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')```

